# Apache-poi how to unhide column upon creation of Excel file

Tags: apache-poi

I am trying to generate an Excel workbook which will be a template.
For now I am trying to generate a workbook with 1 sheet that holds only header cells with values, with certain Height and Width values. The problem is not that I cannot do it, but when I generate/create the .xlsx file the cells are hidden in a certain way and I have to click N(if there are 13 cells) times to display them all.

[Example of how Cells are hidden]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYh1P.png

And the way I want them to be displayed upon creation of the file is like this.

[Example of how I wish them to be displayed uppon creation]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWILw.png

The code is as follows

````
//creating workbook
private static void createWorkBookFile() throws IOException {
  String filePath = "C:\\UltimateMapper\\UltimateMapperProject\\";
  filePath+="\\WriteTestFiles";
  
  System.out.print("Enter name of file: ");
  String fileName = scan.nextLine();
  
  filePath+="\\"+fileName+".xlsx";
  
  XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  
  XSSFSheet currentSheet  = workbook.createSheet("File to STG");
  
  XSSFRow row;
  XSSFCell cell;
  

  
  
  
  //TO DO START FORM HERE FINISH AND THEN INSIDE LOOP
  String[] fileToSTGCellValues_Names = new String[] {"Source Location_Schema","Source File_Table Name",
                                                "Source_Field_Column Name","Start Pos","End Pos",
                                                "Source Field Length","Source Field_Column Data Type",
                                                "Transformation","Target Location_Schema","Target File_Table Name",
                                                "Target Field_Column Name","Target Field_Column Data Type","Comments"};
                                                
  
  HashMap<String,Integer> fileToSTGCellValues_Widths = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
  
  fileToSTGCellValues_Widths.put("Source Location_Schema",26);
  fileToSTGCellValues_Widths.put("Source File_Table Name",26);
  fileToSTGCellValues_Widths.put("Source_Field_Column Name",35);
  fileToSTGCellValues_Widths.put("Start Pos",10);
  fileToSTGCellValues_Widths.put("End Pos",10);
  fileToSTGCellValues_Widths.put("Source Field Length",18);
  fileToSTGCellValues_Widths.put("Source Field_Column Data Type",21);
  fileToSTGCellValues_Widths.put("Transformation",43);
  fileToSTGCellValues_Widths.put("Target Location_Schema",18);
  fileToSTGCellValues_Widths.put("Target File_Table Name",36);
  fileToSTGCellValues_Widths.put("Target Field_Column Name",36);
  fileToSTGCellValues_Widths.put("Target Field_Column Data Type",20);
  fileToSTGCellValues_Widths.put("Comments",47);
  
  int headeRowNumber = 0;
  row =  currentSheet.createRow(headeRowNumber);
  row.setHeightInPoints(28.50f);
  for(int i =0;i<13;i++) {
      currentSheet.setColumnWidth(i, fileToSTGCellValues_Widths.get(fileToSTGCellValues_Names[i]));
      cell = row.createCell(i);
      cell.setCellValue(fileToSTGCellValues_Names[i]);
  }
  
  
  FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
  workbook.write(fout);
  fout.close();
  
  System.out.println("File created");
  
  
}```
````

Comment: The column widths you set using [Sheet.setColumnWidth](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setColumnWidth-int-int-) are too small. "width - - the width in units of 1/256th of a character width": If you need 20 characters column width you need set 20*256.

Comment: thanks this solved my problem :)